# Shortcut to open documentation in VS Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Is there some shortcut to open a class or method documentation like in Visual Studio that we just press F1 over a method or class?

Comment: What are you trying to do, open the browser to the Microsoft Documentation site?

Comment: Yes. Just like in Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

hit F1 when your cursor is over a function or class.

Comment: That opens the command list.

Comment: @gunr2171 Have you tried to put the cursor over the class, then hit ctrl then left click?

Comment: Yes, just did it. It opened the metadata of the class, not a browser.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no shortcuts for online documentation.

The best you have is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> which displays the quick documentation unless there is an extension that allows you to open the Microsoft documentation. To edit the shortcut, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and search for `editor.action.showHover`.

Comment: Sad. Its a cool feature of vs.